# Unable to delete message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const bot = new Discord.Client()
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const token = 'TOKEN'

bot.on('ready' , () =>{
  console.log('Bot has logged in!')
})

const prefix = "!"
bot.on('message' , async (msg) =>{
  if(msg.content[0] !== prefix){
    console.log('No prefix given')
    return
  }
  const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ')
  console.log(args)
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
  console.log(command)

  let num1 = 2;
  if(args[0]){
    num1 = parseInt(args[0]) + 1;
  }


  if(command === 'clear'){
    let num = 2;
    if(args[0]){
      num = parseInt(args[0]) + 1;
    }
    msg.reply(`Are you sure u want to delete ${args[0]} 
    messages Yes or No`)
    command.clear()
  } 
  if(command === 'yes'){
    
    msg.channel.bulkDelete(num1);
    msg.channel.send(`deleted ${args[0]} posts for u`);
  }




})
bot.login(token)
```

I would like to know the issue in my code as the clear and yes command seem to work fine as they output the desired reply, But dont seem to delete the message as they are intended to.
..........................................................................................

Comment: Please regenerate your bot token at https://discord.com/developers/applications/, as you had it in this post, anyone can act as your bot with it.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you would want to use a [message collector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector). It will wait for a message in the channel.

```
if (command === 'clear') {
    let num = 2;
    if (args[0]) {
        num = parseInt(args[0]) + 1;
    }
    msg.reply(`Are you sure u want to delete ${args[0]} 
    messages Yes or No`)
    const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 60000 });
    collector.on('collect', message => {
        if (message.content === 'yes') {
            message.channel.bulkDelete(num1);
            message.channel.send(`deleted ${args[0]} posts for u`);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it did work out but im in a bit of confusion in the declaring of collector statement can you explain it .So i can work out with it later in my journey :) 
thank you!